# Regex to allow alphanumeric characters and should allow . (dot) ' (apostrophe) and - (dash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I am trying to build a Regex to validate name of the user which will be contain alphanumeric characters and should allow `.`  (dot) `'` (apostrophe) and `-` (dash), I have tried with following regex, but they are not working

1. `/^[\w-'.]$/`
2. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.'-]$/`

Please help

Comment: How come you know about character classes but don't know about quantifiers ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things were missing:

- Escape the last dash in the set.  The `-` symbol denotes a range in a set, such as with `a-z`.
- After the set add `+`, so that the characters are matched one or more times.

**Expression**

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\.'\-]+$
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/bhkixz)

You could also revise it to something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9\.'\-]{5,}$`, where the `{5,}` requires a minimum of 5 members of the set matched concurrently.  Usually user names have to be longer than 1 character.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, can you tell me using regex how to validate the string so that the first character must be between A-Z and the second character must not contain a numeric value

Comment: ^[A-Z][a-zA-Z\.'\-][a-zA-Z0-9\.'\-]+$